# getelementbyid not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, getelementbyid

For http://jsfiddle.net/7HWxu/2/ I am trying to override the image loop with the four buttons so that when one is clicked the image changes. However, on click of "1" the image won't change. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Tom

Comment: ?? There is no call to "getElementById()" in that code, is there?

Comment: Nicely spotted!. Wrong jsFiddle link given. Sorry, question now updated with correct link. Thanks

Comment: and there actually isn't any other id than the table one + you're using jquery. why would you use `document.getElementById`?

Comment: Experimenting to see if possible. Would there be a simple solution to override the jquery at all rather than using another jquery gallery?

Comment: Kelly (or Tom?): When asking a question, please remember to include the relevant code directly in the question, then provide supplemental links to other resources if desired. This ensures that your question is useful to future readers when the link may no longer be valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in this code:

```
<div class="fadein">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (1.jpg) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="251" height="61" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/images/1_01.jpg" width="68" height="61" alt=""
    onclick="document.getElementById('fadein').src='/1.jpg'">
</td>
<td>
<img src="/images/1_02.jpg" width="61" height="61" alt="">
</td>
<td>
<img src="/images/1_03.jpg" width="61" height="61" alt="">
</td>
<td>
<img src="/images/1_04.jpg" width="61" height="61" alt="">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</div>
```

You don't have any element with an **id** of "fadein".  (And the `div` element that has a **class** of "fadein" doesn't have a meaningful `src` property.)

I note that you have jQuery on the page - rather than using inline event handlers, I suggest you use `bind` or `delegate` to manage the links:

```
// Your original code
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
          $('.fadein :first-child').
                             fadeOut().
                             next('img').
                             fadeIn().
                             end().
                             appendTo('.fadein');
     }, 6500);

    // Addenda
    $("#Table_01").delegate("img", "click", function(e) {
            // Show and hide images here based on what e.target is.
     });

});
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Sean but how can I implement the show/hide with e.target method in the last part? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Kelly - have a look at the documentation for http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ and jQuery's Event object http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/  `target` is the element that initiated the event (in this case a click). All we need to do is determine which image we should show based on which number was clicked.  We could add a class to both our large images and the numbers (i.e. both `1_01.jpg` and `1.jpg` have a class of `slider1`, `1_02.jpg` and `2.jpg` have a class of `slider2`, etc.) and use `$(".fadein img." + $(e.target).attr("class")).fadeIn()` (to use a terrible example).

Comment: @Kelly - make sure to put your class on the images themselves - `<img class="slider1" ... etc ... >`

Answer (score 1):

There's no element in your HTML with the "id" value "fadein", so the function returns `null` as it should. The outer containing `<div>` has the **class** "fadein", but not "id".  You could change the `<div>` I guess:

```
<div class='fadein' id='fadein'>
```

Comment: Thanks updated. "1" button still does not override though not sure how this works.. http://jsfiddle.net/7HWxu/7/